# Is there a way to deploy both x86 and x64 versions of assemby with WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, 64-bit

I have a WCF service that deploys to both x86 and x64 instances of IIS. The service itself is compiled for AnyCPU. The service uses an C++ assembly, which comes in both varieties of bitness.  Both varieties of bitness are named the same (foo.dll)

Is there a way to deploy both varieties of bitness and have the IIS/WCF figure out on the fly what's needed?  Right now, it's a bit of a nightmare to figure out what to deploy.

Is there a better way?

Comment: How are you loading the c++ dlls currently?

Comment: @SamShiles The interfaces are identical, so there are simply 2 builds.  That works fine.  But when I deploy from my workstation to some dev box, there is always confusion as to what box is what bitness.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public void LoadAssembly()
{
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
     var a = Assembly.Load("foo");
     Type myType = a.GetType("Example");

    // Get the method to call.
    MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("MethodA");

    // Create an instance. 
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

    // Execute the method.
    myMethod.Invoke(obj, null);
}

private System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
     if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
     {
          // return your 32-bit.
     }
     else if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
     {
          // return your 64-bit.
     }
}
```

Useful links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39.aspx